# How this can be valid php syntax

Tags: php, syntax, lint

I used extra a- at the end of first line. If you run against it php linter, it won't detect syntax error.

```
<?php
$a = "variable";a-
$b = "";
```

What construct has been used here ?

Also if you remove last line, it'll start giving out syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see your code as follow :

```
$a = "variable";
a - $b = "";
```

It's not a syntax error, just an undefined constant.

But if you remove the last line, you gets :

```
$a = "variable";a-
```

The expression is not complete, so a syntax error is raised.

Comment: Beat me to it. :")

Comment: It may not be a php syntax error but a good linter should still detect it and show at least a warning. `a` is most likely never defined in the code and also it's an assignment to a temporary.

Comment: I was wrong the `=` operator has precedence over `-`, so `$b = ""` is evaluated before the subtraction. Just to clarify what happens here. :)